# Extracting data from File in zip using Inflator instead of ZipInputStream

Tags: java, compression

I'm provided Base64 encoded  zip file String. I'm trying to unzip it read the content of the file.

**Retriction:**  Use of Inflator Class

I have tried the following code but it is throwing exception.

```
byte[] file = Base64.getDecoder().decode(inputString.getBytes());
Inflater inflater = new Inflater(true);
    inflater.setInput(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(file.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!inflater.finished()) {
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(new String(output, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Exception ith **new Inflator()**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check
```

Exception ith **new Inflator(true)**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid stored block lengths
```

But when I try to use ZipInputStream like the below code then it works perfectly.

```
 ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(file));
    zipInputStream.getNextEntry();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(zipInputStream);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    }
```

What is I'm missing in my first code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Inflater` is for decoding zlib streams, not zip streams.